# How do I delete the first half of a log that is currently being written to?

Tags: linux, logging

I have a large logfile and very limited disk space left on the drive. The logfile is being written to continuously and I do not want to turn off the process writing to it. I need the contents of the logfile to be backed up, so I can't simply delete it. I'm scp'ing the logfile to another drive. How do I delete the first half of the original log to clear up some space?

I will set up log rotation another time, but now I need to keep this alive without losing data.

Comment: The usual way of doing this is to rename the file and then SIGHUP the writing process, causing it to close and reopen the file (well, usually, if it behaves "like normal"). This will truncate the file and preserve the old contents in another file without losing anything. Doing  the same with _half_ of the file only will be hard atomically. Hard, if not impossible.

Comment: wouldn't the time between renaming the file and the sighup still involve the process writing to the original log location?

Comment: Yes, which is the important thing so you do not lose any writes. Renaming the file changes the link (= filesystem name), but the file itself (and all programs that have file descriptors open) continues to exist as before. Then SIGHUP tells the daemon to re-open the file, which it does. But now the name doesn't exist, so it creates a new file instead. Everything before is in the old file with nothing lost, and everything after is in the new file.

Comment: What can I do if the daemon isn't written to interpret a SIGHUP in such a manner?

Comment: Well, in that case, there is no easy and straightforward or reliable way of doing it. As long as the daemon keeps the file descriptor open, it will keep writing to the same file. Short of doing some trickery with creating a LVM snapshot with journal, and then tampering with the snapshot, I see no way how it might be possible at all.